What is the explicit formula for the polynomial sequence $0, 3, 15, 42, 90, 165, 273, 420, \ldots$?
What is the explicit formula for this polynomial sequence?
$$0, 3, 15, 42, 90, 165, 273, 420, 612, 855, 1155, $$
$$1518, 1950, 2457, 3045, 3720, 4488, 5355, 6327, 7410$$
OEIS says $a(n)$ is both the sum of $n+1$ consecutive integers and the sum of the $n$ immediately higher consecutive integers. But I don’t understand this.

Is it $3$ times https://oeis.org/A000330 ?

$a(1)=3$ because $1+2=3$ (sum of $2$ consecutive integers=integer higher than the last consecutive integer, i.e., $2$). $a(2)=15$ because $4+5+6=7+8$ (sum of $3$ consecutive integers=sum of $2$ higher consecutive integers, i.e., higher than $6$). $a(3)=42$ because $9+10+11+12=13+14+15$, etc..

where did this question come from. Contex please

@DonaldSplutterwit Yes it is. A006331, A059270 (this sequence), A002492, A055112, A169607, A220443, and A300758 are different multiples of A000330.

OEIS A059270 is one of mine, with the explicit formula
a(n) = n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/2 given, i.e. a cubic.
I gave the example $$a(5) = 25 + 26 + 27 + 28 + 29 + 30 = 31 + 32 + 33 + 34 + 35 = 165$$
where you have $25 + 26 + 27 + 28 + 29 + 30=165$ as the sum of six $(5+1)$ consecutive integers, and $31 + 32 + 33 + 34 + 35=165$ as the sum of the five immediately higher consecutive integers.
More generally, $$a(n)=(n^2)+(n^2+1)+\cdots+(n^2+n) \\= (n^2+n+1)+(n^2+n+2)+\cdots+(n^2+2n)$$  and so is half of the sum of the integers from $n^2$ through to $n^2+2n$, and that gives $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}=n^3+\tfrac32n^2+\frac12n.$$

(+1) Great answer! OP, see also Roger B. Nelsen, Proof Without Words: Consecutive Sums of Consecutive Integers, Math. Mag., 63 (1990), 25. for some visualization.

@projectilemotion - that is indeed linked from the OEIS entry

$$0=3×0^2\\3=3×1^2\\15=3×5=3×(1^2+2^2)\\
42=3×(1^2+2^2+3^2)$$
As seen above, we notice a pattern. It's $$3×(\text{Sum of squares upto n})\\=3\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$$
If we apply the expanded formula for the summation, it simplifies to Henry's answer,
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}$$

In general, to interpolate/extrapolate a sequence of values $f(n)$ by a polynomial, repeatedly take consecutive differences $f_1(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$. If/when the differences become zero in many fewer steps than the length of the given sample, it is reasonable to suspect that the whole thing is polynomial... and, at least, we have have a polynomial interpolation of the given values, using the properties of $g_N(n)=n(n+1)\ldots(n+N)$ or similar, with respect to the difference operator.
